# Автоматическое создание полей из параметров конструктора с проверкой

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

В Visual Studio можно объявить конструктор класса и задать в нем все необходимые параметры, а потом нажать
CTRL+. и создать приватное поле, которое будет инициализировано в этом же конструкторе.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, что бы создаваемое поле сразу же проверялось в конструкторе?

Скажем, я обычно всегда проверяю ссылочные типы на null и если они null, то кидаю исключение.

```
   _serverConnectionService = serverConnectionService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serverConnectionService));
```

Да... бывают исключения, когда я так не делаю, но в большинстве случаев я именно так и делаю.

Comment: Когда в универе учился мне говорили что программисты лентяи. Вот даже коммент не хотел писать

Comment: в C# proposal есть `void M(string name!)` такой синтакс https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/null-arg-checking.md но пока это только proposal

Comment: Насколько я в курсе, студия "из коробки" так не умеет, вроде решарпер может или можно научить его так делать.

Comment: Нечто подобное умеют и другие расширения, кроме Решарпера. У меня вот сейчас Студия в два нажатия `Ctrl+.` делает именно то, что нужно. Возможно, это делает Roslynator (он у меня стоит). Также можно попробовать FxCop.

Comment: Я любитель давать советы... Пора переходить на `#nullable enable`. Задаёте параметр без знака `?` - проверки на `null` становятся не нужны.

Comment: Ишшо совет: [NullGuard.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/NullGuard). Проверки добавляются автоматически. Коллеги оценят мощь AOP (ай, больно, не надо ногами! только не по голове!)